# How to Detect collision between tile and sprite during scrolling tile map?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am new in cocos2d and now a days I am stucked in tiled map learning.I want to detect collision between sprite and a tile of scrolling Tile map layer.In tile map layer i also set the specific tile value 1 in tile properties.problem is that, how can i detect collision  or coordinates of the tile when it is collide with sprite and my sprite is at fixed position?

```
-(void)Collision:(ccTime)delta{

CGPoint playerPosition=player.position;
CGPoint tileCoordPos = [self tileCoordForPosition:playerPosition]; 
bool isTouchOnWater = NO;


int tileGID = [FloorLayer tileGIDAt:tileCoordPos];

if (tileGID != 0)
{
    NSDictionary* properties = [tileMap propertiesForGID:tileGID];
    if (properties)
    {
        CCLOG(@"NSDictionary 'properties' contains:\n%@", properties);
        NSString* isWaterProperty = [properties valueForKey:@"isWater"];
        isTouchOnWater = ([isWaterProperty boolValue] == YES);
    }
}

if (isTouchOnWater)
{
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"alien-sfx.caf"];
    [FloorLayer removeTileAt:tileCoordPos];
}
```

}

This the code i am using.In this code coordinates of the tile remains same.

Answer (score 2):

I resolve the problem by doing scrolling of the whole map and make two maps one is for ground layer and one for objects and then detect the collision...it works perfect for me